# C++ Cannot find Include

Tags: c++, c++11, include

In `main.cpp` I keep getting errors saying that `print` was not defined (and other errors of the sort.

I have `print()` defined under a header file called "misc"

`misc.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#define MISC_H
#ifndef MISC_H

void print(string str) { cout << str << endl; }

string userIn(string prompt = "Option:") { //For collecting user responses
  string response;
  print(prompt);
  cin.clear();
  cin.sync();
  getline(cin, response);
  if (!cin) { response = "wtf"; }
  else if (response == "512") { //Secret termination code
    print("Program terminated");
    exit(0);
  }
  print("");
  return response;
}
#endif
```

Then in `main.cpp` I `#include Headers/misc.h"` (The header file is located in a separate folder)

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It should #ifndef #define   not #define #ifndef

Comment: ^^ as in, switch them around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's visible to me, without knowing the compile commands you are using, is that your '[include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)' is incorrect.

The first command `#define MISC_H` will cause the macro to begin existing.

After that, when you call `#ifndef MISC_H` it will always be false, because you have just defined it, the effect is that the source of this file is always discarded.

You need to flip those lines to look like this:

```
#ifndef MISC_H
#define MISC_H
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your `#ifndef` and `#define` in the wrong order. It should be:

```
#ifndef MISC_H
#define MISC_H
```

Preferably at the top of the file before other includes.

Answer (score 0):

The `#ifndef MISC_H  ... #endif` block is never reached. MISC_H is defined just prior to that, so it never gets passed the if condition there and your print function is thus never defined.

do it like this:

```
#ifndef MISC_H
#define MISC_H

//Now define what you want to define
```

Though you can omit those altogether and use `#pragma once` instead, if it's available.